# Return on Large JSON String Crashing IIS Express in C#.NET Webpages

Tags: c#, sql, json, ajax, iis-express

I am trying to query a database (SQL) for a large dataset (using JSON) so that I don't have to use AJAX more than once (round trips to the server are expensive, after all) to populate new data as the user interacts with the interface.

I am building the strings manually, while `JSON.Encode`ing and then trying to write it straight to the page so that my `$.ajax` jquery call can receive it on the other side.

**Here's the jQuery**

```
function getAllData(market) {


    $.ajax({
        url: "/AJAX Pages/Compute_Get_Vantrack_Data",
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            market: market
        },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (jsonResponse) {
            jsonObj = jsonResponse;
            alert(jsonObj.companies[2].ID + jsonObj.companies[2].companyName + jsonObj.companies[2].memo);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
            alert("The request to the server has failed. The Vantrack information in your browser may not be populated accurately.\n\n" +
                  "Please reload the page and try again. If the problem persists, please contact an administrator.\n\n" +
                  "Error Type: " + error + "/" + textStatus + "/" + jqXHR)
        }
    });
}
```

**Here's the C# (Compute_Get_Vantrack_Data)**

```
@{
Layout = "";

if(!IsAjax)
{
    var db = Database.Open("CST_DATA");
    string getAllData = "SELECT * FROM Vantrack_";
    string market = Request["market"];
    string jsonString = "{\"companies\":[";

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(market))
    {
        getAllData += market + " ORDER BY [company name] ASC";

        foreach (var row in db.Query(getAllData))
        {
            jsonString += "{" +
            "\"ID\":" + Json.Encode(row["ID"]) + "," +
            "\"companyName\":" + Json.Encode(row["company name"]) + "," +
            "\"companyAddress\":" + Json.Encode(row["company address"]) + "," +
            "\"companyPoBox\":" + Json.Encode(row["company po box"]) + "," +
            "\"companyCity\":" + Json.Encode(row["company city"]) + "," +
            "\"companyState\":" + Json.Encode(row["company state"]) + "," +
            "\"companyZip\":" + Json.Encode(row["company zip"]) + "," +
            "\"companyPoZip\":" + Json.Encode(row["company po zip"]) + "," +
            "\"companyCounty\":" + Json.Encode(row["company county"]) + "," +
            "\"companyCountry\":" + Json.Encode(row["company country"]) + "," +
            "\"companyPhone\":" + Json.Encode(row["company phone"]) + "," +
            "\"company800\":" + Json.Encode(row["company 800"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFax\":" + Json.Encode(row["company fax"]) + "," +
            "\"companyWebsite\":" + Json.Encode(row["company website"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilitySites\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility sites"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation01\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 01"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation02\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 02"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation03\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 03"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation04\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 04"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation05\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 05"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation06\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 06"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation07\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 07"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation08\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 08"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation09\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 09"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation10\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 10"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation11\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 11"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation12\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 12"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation13\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 13"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation14\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 14"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation15\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 15"]) + "," +
            "\"companyFacilityLocation16\":" + Json.Encode(row["company facility location 16"]) + "," +
            "\"companyDrivingDirections\":" + Json.Encode(row["company driving directions"]) + "," +
            "\"parentCorporationName\":" + Json.Encode(row["parent corporation name"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyName\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company name"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyAddress\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company address"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyPoBox\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company po box"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyCity\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company city"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyState\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company state"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyZip\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company zip"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyPoZip\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company po zip"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyCounty\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company county"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyCountry\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company country"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyPhone\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company phone"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompany800\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company 800"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyFax\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company fax"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateCompanyWebsite\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate company website"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateFacilitySites\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate facility sites"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateFacilityLocations\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate facility locations"]) + "," +
            "\"clientStatusClient\":" + Json.Encode(row["client status client"]) + "," +
            "\"clientStatusProspect\":" + Json.Encode(row["client status prospect"]) + "," +
            "\"clientStatusFormer\":" + Json.Encode(row["client status former"]) + "," +
            "\"targetMarket\":" + Json.Encode(row["target market"]) + "," +
            "\"market\":" + Json.Encode(row["market"]) + "," +
            "\"regSpecInitials\":" + Json.Encode(row["reg spec initials"]) + "," +
            "\"contactName1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact name 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactTitle1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact title 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactAuthority1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact authority 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactPhone1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact phone 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactPhoneExt1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact phone ext 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactCell1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact cell 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactFax1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact fax 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactEmail1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact email 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactMassEmail1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact mass email 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactVitalSigns1\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact vital signs 1"]) + "," +
            "\"contactName2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact name 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactTitle2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact title 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactAuthority2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact authority 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactPhone2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact phone 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactPhoneExt2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact phone ext 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactCell2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact cell 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactFax2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact fax 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactEmail2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact email 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactMassEmail2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact mass email 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactVitalSigns2\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact vital signs 2"]) + "," +
            "\"contactName3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact name 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactTitle3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact title 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactAuthority3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact authority 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactPhone3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact phone 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactPhoneExt3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact phone ext 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactCell3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact cell 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactFax3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact fax 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactEmail3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact email 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactMassEmail3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact mass email 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactVitalSigns3\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact vital signs 3"]) + "," +
            "\"contactName4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact name 4"]) + "," +
            "\"contactTitle4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact title 4"]) + "," +
            "\"contactAuthority4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact authority 4"]) + "," +
            "\"contactPhone4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact phone 4"]) + "," +
            "\"contactPhoneExt4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact phone ext 4"]) + "," +
            "\"contactCell4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact cell 4"]) + "," +
            "\"contactFax4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact fax 4"]) + "," +
            "\"contactEmail4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact email 4"]) + "," +
            "\"contactMassEmail4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact mass email 4"]) + "," +
            "\"contactVitalSigns4\":" + Json.Encode(row["contact vital signs 4"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactName1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact name 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactTitle1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact title 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactAuthority1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact authority 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactPhone1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact phone 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactPhoneExt1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact phone ext 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactCell1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact cell 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactFax1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact fax 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactEmail1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact email 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactMassEmail1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact mass email 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactVitalSigns1\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact vital signs 1"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactName2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact name 2"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactTitle2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact title 2"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactAuthority2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact authority 2"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactPhone2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact phone 2"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactPhoneExt2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact phone ext 2"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactCell2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact cell 2"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactFax2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact fax 2"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactEmail2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact email 2"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactMassEmail2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact mass email 2"]) + "," +
            "\"corporateContactVitalSigns2\":" + Json.Encode(row["corporate contact vital signs 2"]) + "," +
            "\"sicCodes\":" + Json.Encode(row["sic codes"]) + "," +
            "\"businessDescription\":" + Json.Encode(row["business description"]) + "," +
            "\"numberOfEmployees\":" + Json.Encode(row["number of employees"]) + "," +
            "\"naics\":" + Json.Encode(row["naics"]) + "," +
            "\"msdsQuantity\":" + Json.Encode(row["msds quantity"]) + "," +
            "\"chemicalsQuantity\":" + Json.Encode(row["chemicals quantity"]) + "," +
            "\"rcraStatus\":" + Json.Encode(row["rcra status"]) + "," +
            "\"yearEstablished\":" + Json.Encode(row["year established"]) + "," +
            "\"annualSales\":" + Json.Encode(row["annual sales"]) + "," +
            "\"fiscalYear\":" + Json.Encode(row["fiscal year"]) + "," +
            "\"appointmentCallBack1\":" + Json.Encode(row["appointment call back 1"]) + "," +
            "\"appointmentDate1\":" + Json.Encode(row["appointment date 1"]) + "," +
            "\"appointmentTime1\":" + Json.Encode(row["appointment time 1"]) + "," +
            "\"appointmentCallBack2\":" + Json.Encode(row["appointment call back 2"]) + "," +
            "\"appointmentDate2\":" + Json.Encode(row["appointment date 2"]) + "," +
            "\"appointmentTime2\":" + Json.Encode(row["appointment time 2"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceActive1\":" + Json.Encode(row["service active 1"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceMonths1\":" + Json.Encode(row["service months 1"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceAmount1\":" + Json.Encode(row["service amount 1"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceRcaNeeds1\":" + Json.Encode(row["service rca needs 1"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceHotPercent1\":" + Json.Encode(row["service hot percent 1"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceActive2\":" + Json.Encode(row["service active 2"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceMonths2\":" + Json.Encode(row["service months 2"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceAmount2\":" + Json.Encode(row["service amount 2"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceRcaNeeds2\":" + Json.Encode(row["service rca needs 2"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceHotPercent2\":" + Json.Encode(row["service hot percent 2"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceActive3\":" + Json.Encode(row["service active 3"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceMonths3\":" + Json.Encode(row["service months 3"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceAmount3\":" + Json.Encode(row["service amount 3"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceRcaNeeds3\":" + Json.Encode(row["service rca needs 3"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceHotPercent3\":" + Json.Encode(row["service hot percent 3"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceActive4\":" + Json.Encode(row["service active 4"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceMonths4\":" + Json.Encode(row["service months 4"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceAmount4\":" + Json.Encode(row["service amount 4"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceRcaNeeds4\":" + Json.Encode(row["service rca needs 4"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceHotPercent4\":" + Json.Encode(row["service hot percent 4"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceActive5\":" + Json.Encode(row["service active 5"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceMonths5\":" + Json.Encode(row["service months 5"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceAmount5\":" + Json.Encode(row["service amount 5"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceRcaNeeds5\":" + Json.Encode(row["service rca needs 5"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceHotPercent5\":" + Json.Encode(row["service hot percent 5"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceActive6\":" + Json.Encode(row["service active 6"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceMonths6\":" + Json.Encode(row["service months 6"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceAmount6\":" + Json.Encode(row["service amount 6"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceRcaNeeds6\":" + Json.Encode(row["service rca needs 6"]) + "," +
            "\"serviceHotPercent6\":" + Json.Encode(row["service hot percent 6"]) + "," +
            "\"memo\": " + Json.Encode(row["memo"]) + 
            "},";
        }

        jsonString = jsonString.TrimEnd(',');
        jsonString += "]}";
@*        *@@Html.Raw(jsonString);
    }
    else
    {
@*        *@@:Incorrect data was sent. Please reload the page and try again. If the problem persists, please contact your database administrator.
    }
}
else
{
@*    *@@:Generic Error! Not a proper AJAX request.
}
```

}

The problem I'm getting is that I keep getting this error (In Windows):

[image]

I'm not sure if this is an IIS-Express only problem, if the data set is too large, or if my use of `JSON.Encode` rather than some kind of other parsing method is causing this issue.

**Things to Note**

- The Table I'm Querying has, not only 174 columns, but 6,468 rows, as well.
- I tried to narrow down whether or not a single column was causing issues, and it starts to error around the `contact phone 1` column, but that columns data type (nvarchar) is no different from so many others, and having a NULL value within it isn't different either.
- Thinking this was a size issue, I decided to SELECT only the TOP (1) Rows, but grab all columns, and the error persists as though I'd selected all rows, and conversely, if I SELECT all rows, but comment out a group of columns (usually including, but not limited to the `contact phone 1` column) I get a MUCH larger dataset returned with no problem.
- I've repaired, compacted, and reconverted the old table twice, with no errors to make sure that it wasn't some quirky error from the migration from Access.
- With just a little less than half of the columns, for all rows, queried, I used C# to write a simple text file (to test its size) and it was 12.5 MB, if that tells you anything about the size of the return I'm looking for here.

Is there a limit on the size of a json string that can be returned through an AJAX call? Is this a limit of IIS-Express (during live hosting, we'll actually be using IIS 8)? or am I doing something else completely wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you're using GET, and there is a limit on the length of a query string (can't remember if it's browser specific or not off the top of my head).

Comment: This may not solve the specific issue you are encountering but using StringBuilder.Append instead of + to concatenate the string will provide a huge performance boost.

Comment: @jsxsl I had no idea. Thank you for that!

Comment: @Tim Actucally, if you'll see my jQuery snippet above, you'll see I'm actually just using `$.ajax` configured to accept json. Not sure if that affects the limit or if that's even a bad way to go about it when you know you're just getting json, but it's never caused me any issues in the past so I just use `$.ajax` as a default for any ajax that I do. Perhaps, not the best idea, idk.

Comment: Analyze the dumps and you will see what is the cause.

Comment: @LexLi Any idea how I do that?

Comment: @jsxsl It appears that StringBuilder.Append isn't an option in the WebPages environment. Even within a .cs file, if I write `using System.Text` I get StringBuilder, but no Append. In the actual `.cshtml` file, I don't even get StringBuilder, so I'm not sure this option is even available to me.

Comment: @VoidKing it works for me. I'll add an example for you.  Add the example to the top of your .cshtml page.

Comment: @using System.Text;

@{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("append some text");
}

Comment: @jsxsl Oh, I see what I was doing wrong, just got it. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem.  Also if you can estimate the number of chars your string will be setting the default capacity will reduce the number of times it needs to re allocate memory.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1h0a5sy(v=vs.110).aspx